# Recyler view item gets selected only on clicking the text

Tags: android, android-layout, drawerlayout, android-recyclerview, actionbardrawertoggle

I have implemented the RecyclerView with an adapter for items and each item has a drawer item layout containing an imageview and a textview.
The problem is that the onClick function is called only when the image or the "actual text" which differs in size is clicked and not the whole row.
Is there a way to make to whole row listen with onClick function? Please let me know if you have any ideas.
Thanks in advance.
[RecyclerView image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMhgW.png)

RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
String[] titles;
TypedArray icons;
Context context;
RecyclerViewAdapter(String[] titles, TypedArray icons, Context context){

        this.titles = titles;
        this.icons = icons;
        this.context = context;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener  {

    TextView navTitle;
    ImageView navIcon;
    Context context;

    public ViewHolder(View drawerItem , int itemType , Context context){

        super(drawerItem);
        this.context = context;
        drawerItem.setOnClickListener(this);
        if(itemType==1){
            navTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_NavTitle);
            navIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_NavIcon);
        }
    }

   /**
    *This defines onClick for every item with respect to its position.
    */

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity)context;
        mainActivity.drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        //switch (getPosition()){
        switch (getAdapterPosition()){
            case 1:
                Fragment fragment = new CountryWise();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;
            case 2:
                Fragment f2 = new CompanyWise();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,f2);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;
            case 3:
                Fragment about = new About();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,about);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(viewType==1){
             View itemLayout =   layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_item_layout,null);
             return new ViewHolder(itemLayout,viewType,context);
        }
        else if (viewType==0) {
            View itemHeader = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.header_layout,null);
            return new ViewHolder(itemHeader,viewType,context);
        }

    return null;
}

   /**
*This method is called by RecyclerView.Adapter to display the data at the specified position.�
*This method should update the contents of the itemView to reflect the item at the given position.
*So here , if position!=0 it implies its a row_item and we set the title and icon of the view.
*/

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if(position!=0){
        holder.navTitle.setText(titles[position - 1]);
        holder.navIcon.setImageResource(icons.getResourceId(position-1,-1));
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(position==0)return 0;
    else return 1;
}
```

}

drawer_item_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/iv_NavIcon"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/tv_NavTitle"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawerMainActivity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Please let me know if you need more code.

Comment: see if your RecyclerView or it's parent view has width wrap_content

Comment: the drawerlayout which contains recyclerview has width as match_parent and changing the textview to match_parent also doesn't work. any other idea?

Comment: Try setting the drawer_item_layout background to #000000 and see if the item is actually full width or only wrapping the content.

Comment: In the meantime, post the layout containing your RecyclerView.

Comment: Yeah it confirmed that the item layouts are not matching the parent though the property is set as match_parent and also setting its width to the width of the drawer_layout doesn't seem to work

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/UAh4W1S.png

Comment: Remove `android:layout_gravity="center"` from your TextView. layout_gravity doesn't work inside LinearLayout. Maybe that's your problem.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work.. and fill_parent also doesn't work in textview or the item_layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Adapter's `onCreateViewHolder()` method, change the `inflate()` calls as follows.

```
if(viewType == 1) {
    View itemLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_item_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(itemLayout, viewType, context);
}
else if(viewType == 0) {
    View itemHeader = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.header_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(itemHeader, viewType, context);
}
```

Your rows aren't matching the `RecyclerView`'s width, because you're not passing `parent` to the Inflater, so it's wrapping the width instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this
Set an id to the parent layout of the RecyclerView in your case the Linear Layout and bind this layout in the View holder and set the onclick to this layout it should work

Comment: Can you please share some code sample? It would be very helpful